# Factory design pattern; parent = new child()

Tags: c#, design-patterns, factory

When I'm using the factory pattern, I'm confused with how to make child classes from it when the child has extra properties/methods. The factory returns the parent type as it works out which child to make but when this happens I can't use what it returns like a child class.

```
public abstract class Factory 
{
        public abstract Person getPerson(string type);
}

public class PersonFactory : Factory
{
        public override Person getPerson(string type) {
               switch (type) {
                      case "admin": 
                             return new Admin();
                      case "customer": 
                             return new Customer();
                      default: 
                             return new Admin();
               }
        }
}


public abstract class Person
{
        public abstract string Type { get; }
        private int _id;

        public int Id
        {
            get { return _id; }
            set { _id = value; }
        }
}

public class Admin : Person
{
        private string _securityRole;

        public Admin()
        {
            Id = 0;
        }

        public override string Type
        {
            get{
                return "admin";
            }
        }

        public string SecurityRole
        {
            get { return _securityRole; }
            set { _securityRole = value; }
        }
}
```

So my question is, when I create a PersonFactory object and decide to use that factory to create other derived classes. I noticed that getPerson() returns Person and not actually type Admin or Customer. How can I make the factory create the child classes so that they are actually child objects?

```
Factory pf = new PersonFactory();
Person admin = pf.getPerson("admin");
admin.Id = 1;            // is fine
admin.SecurityRole       // cannot access
```

Comment: Looking at this code, I wonder if an admin should really 'be' a person - perhaps it should rather be a 'role' on a person.  I realise that this code might be from a tutorial or something, but if it were production code, I would take the Liskov Substitution Principle into account and consider whether or not this is a violation thereof.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

quick fix is this

```
Admin admin = (Admin)pf.getPerson("admin");
```

but better implementation is

1) use static method for your factory class.

2) use generic and interface.

your new code will be:

```
 public class PersonFactory //: Factory
    {
        public static T getPerson<T>() where T: IPerson
        {
            return Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        }
    }


    public interface IPerson
    {
        string Type { get; }
        int Id { get; set; }        
    }

    public class Admin : IPerson
    {
        private string _securityRole;

        public Admin()
        {
            Id = 0;
        }

        public string Type
        {
            get
            {
                return "admin";
            }
        }

        public string SecurityRole
        {
            get { return _securityRole; }
            set { _securityRole = value; }
        }

        public int Id
        {
            get;set;
        }
    }

    public class Customer : IPerson
    {
        private string _securityRole;

        public Customer()
        {
            Id = 0;
        }

        public string Type
        {
            get
            {
                return "customer";
            }
        }

        public string SecurityRole
        {
            get { return _securityRole; }
            set { _securityRole = value; }
        }

        public int Id
        {
            get;set;
        }
    }
```

and how to use:

```
 Admin a = PersonFactory.getPerson<Admin>();

 Customer b = PersonFactory.getPerson<Customer>();
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you cannot access the property is because you are expecting a return type of `Person` for this line of code:

```
Person admin = pf.getPerson("admin");
```

`Person` does not contain a definition of `SecurityRole`. Because you are defining the return type to be `Person` your result is effectively cast back to a `Person` object not an `Admin` object.

You should be able to fix this by going:

```
var admin = pf.getPerson("admin");
```

or by using:

```
Admin admin = pf.getPerson("admin");
```

Comment: var admin = pf.getPerson("admin"); works but i still cant access the child properties/methods

Answer (score 0):

Since `.id` is working but not `.SecurityRole` I think it's safe to say that you made a Person and not an Admin.

Try `Admin admin = pf.getPerson("admin");` instead of `Person admin = pf.getPerson("admin");`

Comment: Admin admin = pf.getPerson("admin"); doesn't seem to work, cannot implicitly convert Person to Admin. I think the method wants to return a Person.

Comment: How about Person admin = new Person; -- Admin realAdmin = admin.getPerson("admin");     Although at this point it should be questioned as to whether or not this is the right design pattern in the first place.